# joining one table to multi others

Tags: mysql

```
i have 3 tables as the following:
```

#### STUDENT

```
---------------
id     name
---------------
1      Joe
2      mark
3      mike
---------------
```

#### SUBJECT

```
-----------------------------------
id    student_id    name
-----------------------------------
1         1          math
2         1          english
3         1          french
4         1          history
5         2          math
6         2          english
7         2          french
8         3          math
9         3          english
-----------------------------------
```

#### EXAM

```
-----------------------------------
ID  Student_id   mark
-----------------------------------
1    1           10
2    1           10
3    1           10
4    1           10
5    2           5
6    2           5
7    2           5
8    3           2
9    3           2
-----------------------------------
```

```
SELECT
    student.id, student.name AS 'NAME',
    COUNT(subject.id) AS 'SUBJECTS',
    SUM(exam.mark) AS 'MARKS'
FROM
    'student'
INNER JOIN subject
ON   subject.student_id = student.id

LEFT JOIN exam
ON exam.student_id = student.id
GROUP BY
    student.id
```

> i want to join between STUDENT and SUBJECT, STUDENT and     EXAM
>   i problem is happening when i join the third table, it
>   duplicates the results.
>
> i succeeded to join the first two tables, but when i join > the third one with them, it duplicates the counts.

## the result i need is:

```
----------------------------------- 
ID       NAME     SUBJECTS     MARKS 
----------------------------------- 
1         joe        4          40
2         mark       3          15
3         mike       2           4
```

Comment: How do you determine which `mark` is for which subject?

Comment: i only need total marks for student, not for each subject @PaulSpiegel

Comment: That's not what I asked. If you think the relation irrelevant - Good luck! You will probably need it.

Comment: The reason for my comments: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf8a669af3ebcdf7ba5f7e5141004a7a

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach here is to do separate aggregations on the `subject` and `exam` tables, and then join them:

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.name AS NAME,
    COALESCE(su.cnt, 0) AS SUBJECTs,
    COALESCE(e.marks, 0) AS MARKS
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT student_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM subject
    GROUP BY student_id
) su
    ON s.id = su.student_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT student_id, SUM(mark) AS marks
    FROM exam
    GROUP BY student_id
) e
    ON s.id = e.student_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that I use left joins above, because perhaps a given student might not have any entry at all in either the `subject` or `exam` tables.  In this case, we would assign his count/sum to zero by default.

Comment: works fine, do you suggest any pdf or course to learn this sql statements, thanks @Tim Biegeleisn

Comment: SQL, like most any language, just takes a lot of practice to master.  Simply gaining abstract hands off knowledge might not teach to hammer out a query as I have done above.

Comment: Can you provide the same code in laravel ORM style? @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: No I can't do that here, but your follow up could be the subject another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the aggregated columns by using a direct query for each student id:

```
select 
  s.id, s.name,
  (select count(*) from subject where student_id = s.id) subjects,
  (select sum(mark) from exam where student_id = s.id) marks
from student s
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpg4a3WKuq6gf84XYBW1Qy/0).

Comment: Can you provide the same code in laravel ORM style? @forpas